# Cannot set a ListView ItemsSource to a custom object list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm trying to create a ListView of recent files that the user has opened in a program. I have used a custom object called `GameFileData` that stores 3 variables, `Path` (string), `Name` (string) and `LastEdited` (DateTime). These details are stored in a List object.

Here's the XAML for the ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="LvRecents" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="5,41,10,35">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="ColName" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="ColLastEdited" Header="Last Edited" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastEdited}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In code-behind, I have a method that executes when the window loads:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LvRecents.Items.Clear();
    List<GameFileData> gfd = Saves.GetRecents();
    LvRecents.ItemsSource = gfd;
}
```

When I run the code with two items in the list, the ListView correctly displays two selectable items, but they have no contents:

[image: The listview shows items without any text]

I have also tried the same with the `Path` variable instead of the `LastEdited`, thinking maybe it's to do with the strange data structure, but I get the same result

**Edit:** As requested, the GameFileData class:

```
public class GameFileData
{
    public string Path;
    public string Name;
    public DateTime LastEdited;

    public GameFileData(string path, string name, DateTime lastEdited)
    {
        Path = path;
        Name = name;
        LastEdited = lastEdited;
    }
}
```

Breakpoints have determined that GetRecents() returns the list correctly

Comment: Make sure that Name and LastEdited are public properties of the GameFileData class. Besides that, you don't need to call `LvRecents.Items.Clear()` before assigning the ItemsSource property.

Comment: Have you checked that `Saves.GetRecents()` really returns items?

Comment: Please show the `GameFileData` class.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yep, done that

Comment: `public string Name;` is a field, which can't be used with data binding. It should be a property: `public string Name { get; }`

Comment: @Clemens I was completely unaware of this. It's now working, perfectly. I also removed `LvRecents.Items.Clear()` which is also working fine, thanks